# Extending a function which is smooth up to the boundary to a larger domain smoothly

Tags: partial-differential-equations, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with smooth boundary, and $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\bar\Omega)$ a function which is smooth up to the boundary. It is easy to use a cutoff function to extend $f$ smoothly to $\mathbb{R}^N$.

**My Question is: Can we get a linear operator  $E: \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\bar\Omega)\to W^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ for** a big number $k$  such that $(Ef)|_{\Omega}=f$  and $||F||_{k}\leq C_k||f||_{L^2}$ (**or $||F||_{L^2}\leq C_k||f||_{L^2}$)** for some constant $C_k$ independent of $f$.

**Analysis of the problem:**
As well known, for any positive integer s, there exists a continuous (w.r.t. $W^s$-norm) linear operator $P_{s}$ from $W^{s}(\Omega)$ into $W^{s}\left(\mathbb{R}^{N}\right)$ such that
$
\left.P_{s} u\right|_{\Omega}=u
$.  So we can always get a $F\in \mathcal{C}^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ such that $F|_{\Omega}=f$ and
$||F||_k\leq C_k||f||_k$. But how can we get an extension $F$ such that $||F||_{k}\leq C_k||f||_{L^2}$

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "smooth up to the boundary" usually means that it is a restriction of a smooth function defined in a neighborhood of $\overline{\Omega}$.  So really, in some sense the extension a little past is just by definition.  You can then cut things off to make your function identically zero outside of a little neighborhood of $\overline{\Omega}$ and so it will extend to all of ${\mathbb{R}}^N$.  That's the simplest way to think of the extension to ${\mathbb{R}}^N$.

There is a way to define a smooth function on a closed set that doesn't reference some sort of extension.  Most generally, this was done by Whitney in the 30s.  You can also check Malgrange's *Ideals of Differentiable Functions* book, Chapter I.  The theorem you are looking for is usually called "Whitney extension theorem".  For the specific case of a smooth boundary (you can just think say halfspace), this was known before.

The extension can be done as a linear operator.  Again, best to perhaps see Malgrange's book, Chapter I.

Comment: Thank you,  wonderful reference.  I am sorry for that I don't have enough scores to click on the triangle symbol in the upper left corner.     In Malgrange's book,  the related theorems seem to adopt the supnorm but not the $L^2$-norm  (or I misunderstand them?).  Have you seen some results like $\|F\|_{L^{2}} \leq C\|f\|_{L^{2}}^{2}$ with $C$ independent of $f$?